# Subquery with join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't understand why it doesn't allow me join inside a subquery.

Please consider the following section of code:

```
SELECT c.num_id
FROM (
  SELECT * 
    FROM staff_salary       as a
    FULL JOIN staff_profile as b
      ON a.num_id = b.num_id
) as c
```

I'm receiving the error:

> The column 'num_id' was specified multiple times for 'c'.

Why is this happening? When I run it without the join statement the subquery works just perfectly.

Comment: Explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Also, what part of the error do you not understand?  It is pretty clear.

Comment: I simply want to merge two tables and then make a filter later on.

Comment: I am more interested why it doesn't work, in my opinion num_id is only specified once for c?

Comment: The problem is that you are using “*” in your subquery.  Don’t do that.  The subquery must return columns that all have unique names, but those two tables have one or more columns with the same name.  So instead of just blindly asking for all of them, specifically name which columns you want to return, and if necessary, change their names to be unique.

Comment: But, when I run the subquery individually it works...

Comment: You are correct! Thank you!

Comment: Because at the top level, they don’t have to have unique column names.  But in other contexts, like a subquery, the columns have to have unique names so that the calling query can refer to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field num_id is present in both staff_salary and staff_profile.
As you are selecting with *, sql has no way to know if you refer to staff_salary.num_id o staff_profile.num_id

You will have to replace * for the list of needed fields, for instance:

```
SELECT c.num_id FROM (
  SELECT a.num_id 
    FROM staff_salary       as a
    FULL JOIN staff_profile as b
      ON a.num_id = b.num_id
) as c
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  If you want all `num_id` in either table, then use `union`:

```
select num_id
from staff_salary
union     -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select num_id
from staff_profile;
```

Comment: I would prefer to use a merge. I am interested in the technical aspects of why it tells me there are multiple num_id for c, after the merge in the subquery there should only be one?

Comment: @uncool . . . No, `select *` selects all columns from all tables in the `from` clause.  And your tables have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use specific column in the inner query. `Wild (*)` is throwing an exception.

```
SELECT c.num_id
FROM (
  SELECT b.num_id
    FROM staff_salary       as a
    FULL JOIN staff_profile as b
      ON a.num_id = b.num_id
) as c
```